# How to inject named logger generic ILogger<T> as ILogger into constructor using IServiceCollection and NLog

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, nlog

I want to inject the generic implementation of `ILogger<MyClass>` into the constructor of `MyClass` without its generic parameters.

Example:

```
public class MyClass
{
  private readonly ILogger _logger;

  // Inject ILogger<MyClass> as type ILogger
  public MyClass(ILogger logger) 
  {
    _logger = logger;
  }
}
```

I basically dont want to write its generic type everytime and would want to have it automagically resolved. Using autofac I've been able to resolve this though due to some constraints its not possible to use autofac.

```
     services.AddLogging(configure =>
     {
       configure.ClearProviders();
       configure.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
       configure.AddNLog();
     });
```

Answer (score 3):

The `ILogger` comes from the dependency-injection-system, and it uses the generic-type to imbue the logger-object with the correct Logger-name (NameSpace.ClassName from the generic-type).

You can do this:

```
public class MyClass
{
  private readonly ILogger _logger;   // Notice no generic

  public MyClass(ILogger<MyClass> logger) 
  {
    _logger = logger;
    _logger.LogInformation("Hello");
  }
}
```

Or you can do this:

```
public class MyClass
{
  private readonly ILogger _logger;   // Notice no generic

  public MyClass(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) 
  {
    _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger(GetType().ToString());  // Performance hit
    _logger.LogInformation("Hello");
  }
}
```

If you don't like MEL-ILogger, then you can just use NLog-Logger directly:

```
public class MyClass
{
  private static readonly NLog.Logger Logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

  public MyClass() 
  {
    Logger.Info("Hello");
  }
}
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/wiki/NLog-GetCurrentClassLogger-and-Microsoft-ILogger